# Having trouble adding mongodb documents into an array in controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, express, ejs

As the title says I am trying to add documents from my mongodb into an array in the controller. The following code is what my controller looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var moviesModel = require("../models/movies");

/* GET /movies/ listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
moviesModel.find({}).where('Price').gt(10000).exec(function(err,movies){

    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(movies);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The code above console logs 5 docs. Those are the docs I am trying to add to an array. My goal is to insert the docs into an array then iterate through each element and display it through the view. I dont konw if this is possible. If you have suggestions as to how I should approach this please let me know. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to pass your `movies` to the view through the second argument of `res.render` method:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var moviesModel = require("../models/movies");

/* GET /movies/ listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    moviesModel.find({}).where('Price').gt(10000).exec(function(err,movies){    
       if(err) throw err;
       console.log(movies);

       res.render('layout.ejs', {movies: movies});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and the second step is looping through `movies` in the view and output in the format you desire like the following:

layout.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <title>My movies</title>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
       <% for(var i=0; i<movies.length; i++) {%>
          <li><%= movies[i] %></li>
       <% } %>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thank you that worked! One follow up question I have is , if I wanted to manipulate that array would I do all the manipulation on the ejs file? Or what I add a script to it?

Comment: According to best practices view is only to display your data in appropriate format. So, it would be better to manipulate your data outside the view.